# Get an event page url for Sentry

Tags: python, monitoring, sentry

Sentry's event url pattern looks like this `https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/issues/{issue_id}/events/{event_id}/`.

I can get `event_id` from [last_event_id](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/dd85044c0ec76b19bc7f5b2984c3d4dcc47567ed/sentry_sdk/api.py#L233)

Is there a way to get `issue_id` with a known `event_id` or to use only `event_id` to get an event page URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [sources](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/943a9a7c31d36589daeb509c837badf6f7ffe7f1/src/sentry/web/urls.py#L692).

Sentry have a redirect from `https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/events/{event_id}` to `https://{host}/{organization}/{project}/issues/{issue_id}/events/{event_id}`

So a known `event_id` will be enough to get an event page url